# dynamic drop down select menu in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a dynamic drop down menu displaying states and corresponding cities, in ruby on rails.

I am getting this error (in `/home/yash/socialnw20/app/assets/javascripts/dynamic_cities.js.erb`):

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Javascript file:

```
var cities = new Array();

<% for city in @cities do %>
  cities.push(new Array(<%= city.states_id %>, '<%=h city.name %>', <%= city.id %>));
<% end %>

function stateSelected() {
  states.id = $('states.id').getValue();
  options = $('city.id').options;
  options.length = 1;
  cities.ready(function(city) {
    if (city[0] == states.id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(city[1], city[2]);
    }
  }); 
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('city.field').hide();
  } 
  else {
    $('city.field').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $('city.field').hide();
  $('states.id').observe('change', stateSelected);
});
```

Comment: How is you controller defined? The error its because your @cities its empty.

Comment: class JavascriptsController < ApplicationController
 def dynamic_cities
   @cities = City.find(:all)
 end
end

Comment: I have inputted values in my city table.Please help